# How to simplify these group by queries in Rails 4?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

Schema:

```
Word - 1:n - Training
WordList - 1:n - Word
```

I have the title of a word list and want to create word training statistics for it.

These would be the two SQL queries I was thinking of:

```
myId = SELECT word_list.id as id FROM word_lists WHERE title = 'mytitle'

SELECT words.*, count(trainings.word_id) as timesTrained
FROM words, trainings
WHERE
    words.word_list_id = myId
    trainings.word_id = words.id
GROUP BY trainings.word_id
```

In Rails, this is my current approach. How can I make this shorter, so it takes two queries, instead of many?

```
list = WordList.where(:title => params['wordlist'])
words = Word.where(:word_list => list)
for w in words
  w['timesTrained'] = Training.group(:word_id).where(:word_id => w.id).count()[w.id]
end
```

**UPDATE**
My first query didn't work, what I need is the following query (which I checked, works in psql), as easy as possible in Rails:

```
SELECT words.*, p.ct
FROM words LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT trainings.word_id, count(trainings.word_id) as ct
     FROM trainings
     GROUP BY trainings.word_id) as p
ON words.id = p.word_id;
```

Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: My AREL isn't good enough for the loop, but for the first two, you should be able to do this: `words = Word.where(:word_list => { :title => params['wordlist] })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first can be:

`my_id = WordList.where(title: params['wordList']).pluck(:id).first`

The second can be:

```
words = Word.select('words.*, count(trainings.word_id) as times_trained').
joins("LEFT JOIN trainings on trainings.word_id = words.id").
where(word_list_id: my_id).
group("trainings.word_id")
```

(This is completely untested, so let me know if you have problems you can't sort out and I'll update the question.)

Access your values:

```
words.each { |w| puts "#{w.id}: #{w.times_trained}" }
```

The first query could use 'find_by', which may be better if you want to throw an exception if more than one title of the same name is found.

EDIT:

Your further query in your edit:

```
SELECT words.*, p.ct
FROM words LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT trainings.word_id, count(trainings.word_id) as ct
     FROM trainings
     GROUP BY trainings.word_id) as p
ON words.id = p.word_id;
```

Using ActiveRecord we're forced to use string interpolation to join to a subtable. Something along these lines should work:

```
subquery = Training.select("trainings.word_id, count(trainings.word_id) as ct").
                    group(:word_id)

Word.select("words.*, p.ct").
     joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN (#{subquery.to_sql) as p ON words.id = p.word_id")
```

Deferring the .to_sql until you need it in the string interpolation means that `subquery` can be composed and modified with further ActiveRecord/Arel/Squeel clauses later on. In fact, it's a good idea not to use a local variable at all, but instead build a query object to encapsulate your behaviour and have `subquery` as a method. (Probably with a better name than that.)

Comment: Hm, that produces: `"SELECT words.*, COUNT(trainings.word_id) as timesTrained FROM "words" trainings ON trainings.word_id = words.id WHERE "words"."word_list_id" = 3 GROUP BY trainings.word_id"` and throws syntax error near 'on'

Comment: If I change to `LEFT JOIN trainings on ...` I get: `Error: column "words.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Comment: You were correct to add 'LEFT JOIN' to the query, I missed that out. Answer updated to reflect your edit.

Comment: Thanks, works now! I think it doesn't look too beautiful (SQL mixed with rails), but it does the job!

Comment: I agree. There are ways to make it less ugly, including using Arel (which abstracts SQL well but is still ugly) and the Squeel gem, which is much more natural and beautiful to read and merges in with ActiveRecord much more cleanly. Squeel doesn't support joins to subqueries unfortunately, so that join clause would still use string interpolation. An Arel query will always eventually need to use a '.to_sql' in order to work. For example: `MyModel.find_by_sql(arel_query.to_sql)`